# Typescript conditional is null

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to create a function that takes an argument that is usually an object but might be null/undefined, and conditionally return the type if it's non-null, otherwise null.

```
function objOrNull<T>(t: T): T extends null ? null: T {
   if (t == null) return null;
   
   return t;
}
```

This function signature seems correct, I can call this with `objOrNull({})`, `objOrNull({a:42})`, `objOrNull(null)`, `objOrNull(undefined)` and the returned variable has the expected type.
But the function body fails to compile since neither `return null` nor `return t` is assignable to the declared return type.
If I declare the return type as `T | null`, the function compiles, but whenever I call it, the type I get back is potentially null, which is obviously not what I want - it should be possible to determine in runtime that if `t` is null the returned value is also null, otherwise it's not?

Short of adding `as any` or similar ugly type casts, is there a "correct" way to implement such a function? For a value, what is the equivalent of the conditional type `extends null ?`? Why doesn't `== null` tell the compiler that I'm in the `T extends null` condition?

(My original use-case was a function that takes an object or null, and if the object is null returns null, otherwise returns a variant of the object with some properties added and some removed, but reducing the question to my core question.)
My original usecase

Comment: Did you try `=== null`? I suspect that `==` could trick the type checker because the condition is also true for `0` and `undefined` and other falsy things.

Comment: Look into [user defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

Comment: There's a canonical-ish answer for why the compiler can't verify assignability to conditional types that depend on unspecified generic type parameters, but your function doesn't do what it says it does.  `undefined` doesn't extend `null` (assuming you're using `--strictNullChecks`).  Perhaps you want something like `function objOrNull<T>(t: T): T extends undefined ? null : T { return (typeof t === "undefined") ? null : t; }` instead?  That code has the same problem but at least actually does what you say it's doing.

Answer (score 3):

This is basically a current design limitation in TypeScript.  The compiler does not use [control flow analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8010) to narrow the type of *unspecified generic type parameters* (like `T` inside your function implementation), nor does it use it to narrow the type of *values* that depend on such type parameters (like `t` inside your function implementation).

This means that the compiler cannot verify that a value is assignable to a conditional type like `T extends undefined ? null : T`.  Even if you check `(typeof t === "undefined")`, the control flow analysis that would normally narrow `t` from something concrete like `string | undefined` to `undefined` doesn't kick in for a type like `T`.  Even if it did narrow `t` from `T` to (say) `T & undefined`, it doesn't narrow `T` *itself* to `undefined`, which is what would have to happen for the compiler to realize that `null` is assignable to `T extends undefined ? null : T`.

There's a canonical issue for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), asking for some way of having the compiler use control flow analysis to verify assignability of return values to generic conditional types.  But I don't know if or when this will get addressed (although it's at least a good sign that it was proposed by one of the core members of the TS team).

---

This means that the best thing you can do for now is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) (what you're calling an "ugly cast"):

```
function objOrNull<T>(t: T): T extends undefined ? null : T {
    return (typeof t === "undefined") ? null : t as any;
}
```

or the moral equivalent like a single call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
function objOrNull<T>(t: T): T extends undefined ? null : T;
function objOrNull<T>(t: T): T | null {
    return (typeof t === "undefined") ? null : t;
}
```

That overload doesn't require you to use a type assertion, but it is unsafe in a similar way that using a type assertion.  Meaning: either way should work to calm the compiler down, although it is not actually *verifying* safety here.  That's *your* job since the compiler can't do it:

```
function badObjOrNull<T>(t: T): T extends undefined ? null : T {
    return (typeof t !== "undefined") ? null : t as any; // oops
}
```

or

```
function badObjOrNull<T>(t: T): T extends undefined ? null : T;
function badObjOrNull<T>(t: T): T | null {
    return (typeof t !== "undefined") ? null : t; // oops
}
```

Assuming you implement it properly, however, it should still behave as you expect from the caller's side:

```
const x = objOrNull(undefined); // null
console.log(x); // null

const y = objOrNull(Math.random() < 0.5 ? undefined : "hello"); // "hello" | null
console.log(y); // sometimes null, sometimes "hello"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBKUICcAuBLA9sEgN4BQpSlSAZgK7Dx6FL4BGAVgPKYBytANvwA8AFQB8ACmwAuJCICUskUggAPbBGAATKEnpaI1XMAhakAfiTAB-JEpIUqTzBGy1MRKQE8YEfNSRsJABeUKQAIn1DY1Nw+QsrGztApBBdEGAvAG5HSgBfcic6BiYiVhAtTg5uPkFRSRk5RTkVdU0dPW1okzNLa0Fk5TInZ1d3T2wfPwCggEIwyK6jHriE-ttZILTUzKykAHp9lnwYKFykAsKqeEIoINUQlmreGwko5dN5PcPEwXOb4BQfD8CAAOn4+AA5hJVF8Dkd1ldKAC7kgvI82FwXoIJABZEDYAAWoMwGS0+DAEniQiQAAZQQBWBLvGJmWThQkQQT4OLfI4crkQ8JIAA+v34-1uwLBEOhXjhPyBkDwkF06wANEgla5cKqIpzucLyJdQKq4IgkJwAG5YCEVBznYqMAhETE1Gz1KRKZrKNQabS6Fk9NZJJQ5Ir0Z3MN3Y4TiL1Nexi9YOEZUFxuDxIby+fwpULBCJB2LxPqhwLhqiXCMlF1IcqVZ61OMNb32P3tQNLVkhgZhx2R0r1ipVLHNz2NBRJ8WptNIDPjbOTXMzJDzQuLAwfLSrMt9ivw46nc6XSWA+4YpuvYtaBUImxnoEg8FQmF38VIpAooLowsx5t4gSxKktoFJUkgNL0kylg3skAqGu+8FCqKH5OCi0ovnK77aiq0DipqOG6nhSE8saQA)

Answer (score 2):

You can use overloads to get the same result

```
function objOrNull(t:null|undefined):null
function objOrNull<T>(t: T):T
function objOrNull<T>(t: T|null):T|null {
   return t == null ? null : t;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABHARgKwPICcByIA2+AFFAFxgH4A+4AJgKbAxj20CU5lAUKJLAsnTY8hADwAVAHwlSicR3E9w0eElSZclCdLJyqFQgv2VEAby6JLWelBBYkURAF4niA-kQB+NydlQA3FwAvlxc+DaIAIbOghoixADkCWxhESgx6sKURO4p4Y4QGUKahER0jMysKUA)

Comment: So `objOrNull(Math.random()<0.5 ? "hello" : undefined);` returns what type?

Comment: it returns `string | undefined`.

Comment: But it shouldn’t do that, right?  It should be `string | null`.  The fact that it says it could return `undefined` instead of `null` is a problem.